# Input/comparing strings, Returning number, Java

Tags: java, string, unicode

Recently, I've been trying to build a program that does 4 things:

1) Enter a word from the keyboard.

2) Check the context of this word with the context of a string that contains the letters of the alphabet.

3) Compare the letters of the given word with the letters of the alphabet string and whenever there is match, it will return the position of that letter in the alphabet string +1. (ex. word='a' position=1 since 'a' is the first letter)

4) Get the total of all of these positions.(ex. word='abc' total=6)

Now let me show you what I've written in terms of code.

```
//Part 1 Entering word from keyboard
```

package IntroductionJava;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Numerology 
{

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
{

    int m=0,n=0,sum=0;
    int j,k;


    Scanner user_input=new Scanner(System.in);

    String word;
    System.out.print("Give a word: ");
    word=user_input.next();
```

String word1 = "\u03b1\u03b2\u03b3\u03b4\u03b5\u03b6\u03b7\u03b8\u03b9\u03ba\u03bb\u03bc\u03bd\u03be\u03bf\u03c0\u03c1\u03c3\u03c2\u03c4\u03c5\u03c6\u03c7\u03c8\u03c9";

//Part 2 check word

    for(int i=0; i<word.length(); i++)
    {

        if(word.charAt(i)>=word1.charAt(0) && word.charAt(i)<=word1.charAt(word1.length()-1))
        {
            System.out.println("Your word '"+word+"' is valid.");
            break;
        }

        else
        {
            System.out.println("Your word '"+word+"' is invalid.");
        }
        break;
        //show System.out.print(word.charAt(i));
    }

    //Part 3 Compare letters

    for(j=0; j<word.length(); j++)
    {
        for(k=0; k<word1.length(); k++)
        {
            if(word.charAt(j)==word1.charAt(k))//???
            {
                m=k+1;
            }

        }

    }


}

Now, Part 1 and 2 are working fine.

My problem lies when I try to compare the letters of the word that I'm entering with the String of letters in unicode format(the letters in unicode format are from the Greek alphabet). I've tried many variations, I've also consulted some of the articles here but I couldn't find a solution.

To make things a bit more clear let's say that I'm entering the word: "hello". I want to check whether 'h' is inside the alphabet string, and if it is I want to get it's position as an integer which in our case it's the number '8' (position in the string +1) and so on.

And the last part of my program is to get all those numbers from the given word and get it's total ('hello'=8+5+12+12+20=57).

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: "I've tried many variations, I've also consulted some of the articles here but I couldn't find a solution." That is not a question. We will not write your code for you.

Comment: I'm confused. Why would you expect the value 8 for the letter 'h', if the alphabet is the greek alphabet? The greek alphabet doesn't have the letter 'h', does it?

Comment: I'm afraid I don't see how this could possibly work. Your 'hello' example is assigning a score to each letter based on its position in the English alphabet. Then you talk about Unicode characters and the Greek alphabet. How are you planning on assigning a score to those characters?

Comment: Also, you're supposed to compute a sum, but there is no `+` in your code.

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
String alphabet = "abcdefgh";
String input = "abc";
int value = input.chars()
    .map(alphabet::indexOf)
    .map(i -> i + 1)
    .sum()

System.out.println(value);
```